# Trying to get shipping fields with a new custome field created

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to get the array for all the shipping forms with a new custom element that I already added. This code is not working:

```
$newObj = new WC_Checkout();
$shipping_fields = $newObj->get_checkout_fields($fieldset = 'shipping');
```

Woocommerce WC_Checkout methods:

Visit https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#197-281 for more info!
https://superuser.com?

I get NULL so the object is not existing

In detail:

I'm developing a website, where the total price is calculated according to a delivery area in some city. I decided to create a custom field within the shipping-form:

```
// Adding districts for the city of Lima on shipping form

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_district_checkout_field');

function custom_district_checkout_field($fields) {
   //the list for this example was shortened
   $option_cities = array(
      ''            =>__('Select your district'),
      'chorrillos'  =>'Chorrillos',
      'miraflores'  =>'Miraflores'
};

$fields['shipping']['shipping_district']['type'] = 'select';
$fields['shipping']['shipping_district']['options'] = $option_cities;
$fields['shipping']['shipping_district']['class'] = array('update_totals_on_change');
$fields['shipping']['shipping_district']['input_class'] = array('wc-enhanced-select');

$fields['billing']['billing_district']['type'] = 'select';
$fields['billing']['billing_district']['options'] = $option_cities;
$fields['billing']['billing_district']['input_class'] = array('wc-enhanced-select');

wc_enqueue_js("jQuery( ':input.wc-enhanced-select' ).filter( ':not(.enhanced)' ).each( function() {var select2_args = { minimumResultsForSearch:5};jQuery( this ).select2( select2_args ).addClass( 'enhanced' );})");

return $fields;
```

I can confirm that the custome field is working. For other hand I'm trying to change the way the WooCommerce Advance Shipping plugin works as Jeroen Sormani (who is the developer) explain in his blogs:

[How the plugin works!](https://aceplugins.com/doc/advanced-shipping-for-woocommerce/woocommerce-advanced-shipping-conditions-explained/)
 and [WAS Shipping fields conditions](https://gist.github.com/JeroenSormani/e3108b66c53485e6a8c9#file-was-shipping-fields-php)

The idea is to add to the condition list the shipping fields, the plugin shows by default this fields: [WC Advanced Shipping Fields by Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwA8k.png)

The goal is to been able to select the newly created field in the conditions (for example: "districts") so the price would appear in the cart when the user select the correct option, the plugin already has a list of the different districts with their respective prices. However, there is an error in the plugin because this line is not working (check the Github for the WAS Shipping fields conditions inside the first function:

```
$shipping_fields = WC()->checkout()->checkout_fields['shipping'];
```

I have been trying to solve this for weeks, hence the original ask in this post.

```
/**
* WAS all checkout fields
*/


add_filter('was_conditions', 'was_conditions_add_shipping_fields', 10, 1);

function was_conditions_add_shipping_fields($conditions) {

    $newObj = new WC_Checkout();
    $shipping_fields = $newObj->get_checkout_fields($fieldset = 'shipping');

    debugToConsole($shipping_fields);

    foreach ($shipping_fields as $key => $values) :
        if (isset($values['label'])) :
            $conditions['Shipping Fields'][$key] = $values['label'];
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return $conditions;
}
```

The above results in a NULL with the debugToConsole function.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works… So may be you should give more context showing where are you using this code.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, I always follow your answers on the site, I learn a lot, thank you very much for your interest in helping me.